# Cannot connect to CosmosDb from Azure Bot using Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, botframework, azure-cosmosdb

Can someone please take a look at this code and tell me why I am getting the below error message. I have looked at this every which way and can't understand why or where it's breaking.

The below code shows hard values for docDbClient, but I have also used the "process.env.Document..." system variables to no effect. This is largely taken from the Node Botbuilder samples found online. It is supposed to connect to a CosmosDb database. This should just power up. Using the Bot Framework Emulator, produces the error message at the command prompt where the server is running. Trying via published web page, it just breaks with no error message.

Thank you, in advance!

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var botbuilder_azure = require("botbuilder-azure");
var builder_cognitiveservices = require('botbuilder-cognitiveservices');

// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function() {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});

// Create chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework Service
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword,
    openIdMetadata: process.env.BotOpenIdMetadata
});

// Listen for messages from users 
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

var docDbClient = new botbuilder_azure.DocumentDbClient({
    host: 'https://xxxxx.table.cosmosdb.azure.com:443',
    masterKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    database: 'TablesDB',
    collection: 'botdata'
});

var tableStorage = new botbuilder_azure.AzureBotStorage({ gzipData: false }, docDbClient);

// Create your bot with a function to receive messages from the user
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function(session) {
    session.send('You said: %s', session.message.text);
    session.endDialog();
}).set('storage', tableStorage); // Register in Azure Storage
```

Error:

```
Error: Failed to initialize azure table client. Error: Error: Error Code:
400 Error Body: {"odata.error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":{"lang":"en-
us","value":"One of the input values is invalid.\r\nActivityId: 676a8f3c-
f287-490c-9062-021cb29ff78a, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.20.0 Host/64-bit 
MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0\nRequestID:676a8f3c-f287-490c-9062-
021cb29ff78a\n"}}}

at C:\...\Coffee-Bot\node_modules\botbuilder-azure\lib\AzureBotStorage.js:177:32
at C:\...\Coffee-Bot\node_modules\botbuilder-azure\lib\DocumentDbClient.js:15:17
at C:\...\Coffee-Bot\node_modules\botbuilder-azure\lib\DocumentDbClient.js:76:17
at C:\...\Coffee-Bot\node_modules\documentdb\lib\queryIterator.js:141:28
at C:\...\Coffee-Bot\node_modules\documentdb\lib\queryExecutionContext\proxyQueryExecutionContext.js:71:32
at C:\...\Coffee-Bot\node_modules\documentdb\lib\queryExecutionContext\defaultQueryExecutionContext.js:62:17
at C:\...\Coffee-Bot\node_modules\documentdb\lib\queryExecutionContext\defaultQueryExecutionContext.js:81:32
at C:\...\Coffee-Bot\node_modules\documentdb\lib\queryExecutionContext\defaultQueryExecutionContext.js:136:28
at successCallback (C:\...\Coffee-Bot\node_modules\documentdb\lib\documentclient.js:2360:33)
at C:\...\Coffee-Bot\node_modules\documentdb\lib\documentclient.js:2410:25
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing a Cosmos DB *Table* endpoint and a *DocumentDB* client instance, which explains the `400 Bad Request`.

For DocumentDB API (note `host` has `.documents.` not `.table.`):

```
var docDbClient = new botbuilder_azure.DocumentDbClient({
    host: 'https://xxxxx.documents.cosmosdb.azure.com:443',
    masterKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    database: 'botdocs',
    collection: 'botdata'
});

var tableStorage = new botbuilder_azure.AzureBotStorage({ gzipData: false }, docDbClient);
```

To use Azure Table storage for bot state (this is regular Table storage, as in storage account, not Cosmos DB Table API):

```
var azureTableClient = new azure.AzureTableClient(tableName, storageName, storageKey);
var tableStorage = new azure.AzureBotStorage({gzipData: false}, azureTableClient);
```

In theory, [if you pass a Cosmos DB Table endpoint](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/Node/src/AzureTableClient.ts#L49) to `azure.AzureTableClient()` you can use Cosmos as Table storage, the Table APIs are compatible between Azure Storage and Cosmos. I don't see any immediate benefit over standard DocumentDB type.

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state-azure-cosmosdb
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state-azure-table-storage

Comment: Ok, I think I see what your saying (though it may come with questions after I try tackling). Originally, I was using table storage but it would only log the conversation meta data. Again, it was setup like the examples but simply wouldn't capture the conversation.

Comment: I resolved this particular issue but it still isn't posting. I'm getting "Error: Failed to initialize azure table client. Error: Error: Error Code: ECONNRESET Error Body: undefined". Why would the body be undefined?

Comment: I should add that the "Body: undefined" error is when testing using the emulator connecting with "https://localhost:3978". If I use the actual host endpoint and run online, the first user post produces a 502 bot timed out error. After that, chat posts return status 200 but still doesn't post to database.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing wrong but just follow the sample here - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-nodejs-tutorial-build-bot-framework-sample.md#modify-the-bot-code